# elementary os uvd error

Tags: boot, amd

I successfully installed elementary OS, but i get the following error when i boot the os.

```
*ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
```

I have an AMD radoen hd 6000 graphics card and Intel 3000 series inbuilt graphics card, but the amd graphic card does not work at all which is one of the reason for this error to occur. I bypassed the error by setting nomodeset but this allows the OS to work without the graphic card and also i use dual screen which does not work when nomodset is set.
Please advise me , i need to the OS to run with intel inbuilt graphics card.

Note: I am using Hp laptop.

Comment: Try installing fglrx

Comment: When i install amd drivers or fglrx i get a black screen, as my amd graphic card is corrupted, this happens even on windows which is why i only use intel graphics card

Comment: Do you mean the GPU is damaged.I recommend you fix it but you can also try blacklisting the ```radeon``` module (which is what gives you the AMD GPU) after reinstalling elementary OS (since we installed fglrx) using recovery (if you can boot into it) or a Live USB / CD

Comment: Yes GPU is damaged, i will try blacklisting radeon completely and let you know.

Comment: What model is your laptop ?

Comment: hp dv6165tx i7 2nd gen

Comment: When did the GPU fail and what were you doing when it happened.Sometimes you might be able to fix it by putting it in the oven but first try the blacklisting trick